# WP Custom Page Duplicating Content

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I am building a new blog template using a child theme in Genesis. When I look at the page it is duplicating the content once as a article with the class post and another time as an article with the class page.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Template Name: Articles
 */

remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_close', 15 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );

// remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'inc_do_bc_content' );
function inc_do_bc_content() {

    echo '<div class="breadcrumbs-menu">';
        get_breadcrumb();
        // navigation
        require(CHILD_DIR .'/partials/blog/navigation.php');
    // echo '</div>';

}

add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'inc_do_nav_content' );
function inc_do_nav_content() {

echo '<div class="wp-block-cover alignfull">
        <div class="page-content">';



// today's devotion
echo '<div class="ccb-row fixed-width-md post-row-content">';

}

// "today's devotion"
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'incourage_latest_post' );

add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'inc_do_blog_content' );
function inc_do_blog_content() {

    // end today's devotion
    echo '</div>';

    // subscribe
    require(CHILD_DIR .'/partials/blog/subscribe.php');

    // recent posts
    require(CHILD_DIR .'/partials/blog/recent.php');

    // authors
    // require(CHILD_DIR .'/partials/blog/authors.php');

    // community image
    require(CHILD_DIR .'/partials/blog/bottom.php');

    echo '    </div><!-- end wp-block-cover-->
    </div><!-- end page-content-->';
}

genesis();
```

I have not had this issue before, so I am kind of stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the genesis_entry_content hook, try the genesis_loop hook but remove the default loop first using

```
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'inc_do_blog_content' );
```